# Queryset to update set of values for a field

Tags: django, django-models

What queryset can I use to translate the values of a field from one set of values to another set? For example, lets say I have a User model with a CharField containing the name of a country and I wish to update the name of some of the countries for all users using the following dict:

```
new_country_names = {"Micronesia": "States of Micronesia", "Macedonia": "North Macedonia"}
```

I obviously want to avoid doing this by looping over each user and checking the value of their country.

Comment: The key in your dict is the old name ? And the value is new name ?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes in my mind (several DB hits):

```py
for old, new in new_country_names.items():
    User.objects.filter(country=old).update(country=new)
```

Another solution can be using `case, when` (one DB hit):

```py
User.objects.update(
    country=Coalesce(
        Case(
            *[When(country=old_name, then=Value(new_name)) for old_name, new_name in new_country_names.items()]
        ),
        User.country,
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two hits with:

```
new_country_names = {
    'Micronesia': 'States of Micronesia',
    'Macedonia': 'North Macedonia',
}

users = list(User.objects.filter(country__in=new_country_names))
for user in users:
    user.country = new_country_names.get(user.country)
User.objects.bulk_update(users, fields=('country',))
```